# Как правильно выполнить Триангуляцию Делоне для прямоугольника?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, геометрия

Исходя из определения триангуляции Делоне:

> триангуляция для заданного множества точек S на плоскости, при которой для любого треугольника все точки из S за исключением точек, являющихся его вершинами, лежат вне окружности, описанной вокруг треугольника

правильно ли, что верная триангуляция (Делоне!) для подобного полигона: {{1, 1}, {1, 100}, {2, 100}, {2, 1}}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

невозможна? Ведь окружность, проводимая из любого полученного треугольника будет содержать все точки полигона (прямоугольника).

Comment: Для получения валидной триангуляции в этом случае достаточно провести диагональ (любую).

Comment: зы само определение немного кривое, не должно быть других точек внутри окружности. А если они есть на самой окружности (что происходит в случае любого прямоугольника), то триангуляция не будет единственной.

Comment: @user7860670 по поводу диагонали - это я надеюсь вы просто пошутили... Я думаю любой человек понимает, что премоугольник был взят в качестве минимального примера (не зря я писал `полигон` описывая фигуру)

Comment: *"по поводу диагонали - это я надеюсь вы просто пошутили..."* - ни в коем случае... *"Я думаю любой человек понимает, что премоугольник был взят в качестве минимального примера"* - и?..

Comment: @user7860670 и то что этот ваш "совет" не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу

Comment: Как это не имеет? Это прямой ответ на вопрос *"правильно ли, что верная триангуляция для подобного полигона: {{1, 1}, {1, 100}, {2, 100}, {2, 1}} невозможна?"* - Для получения валидной триангуляции в этом случае достаточно провести диагональ (любую). Что вам тут не понятно?

Comment: @user7860670 у вас видно дислексия: вы видели что приводимая вами цитата - это предложение с середины? Она даже с маленькой буквы начинается! Ну очевидно что речь идёт о триангуляции Делоне

Comment: И что, вас смущает, что триангуляция Делоне для прямоугольника достигается проведением диагонали? т.е. прямоугольник просто разбивается на два одинаковых прямоугольных треугольника.

Comment: @user7860670, а критерий из цитаты проверить не хочешь для своей диагонали?

Comment: @Qwertiy Определение из цитаты не точное, я же во втором комменте пояснил.

Comment: @user7860670, так определение из википедии взято...

Comment: @Qwertiy хм, вот на [англ. странице](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) определение корректное: In mathematics and computational geometry, a Delaunay triangulation (also known as a Delone triangulation) for a given set P of discrete points in a plane is a triangulation DT(P) such that no point in P is **inside** the circumcircle of any triangle in DT(P).

Comment: А вот и цитата из книжки Скворцова, которая в статье в разделе Примечания: Определение 6. Говорят, что триангуляция удовлетворяет условию Делоне, если внутрь окружности, описанной вокруг любого построенного треугольника, не попадает ни одна из заданных точек триангуляции.

Comment: @user7860670, тогда ответ писать надо ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy я бы может и написал, но ОП на меня что-то серчает всякой "дислексией", непонятно, что ему надо...

Comment: @user7860670, так надо просто понятно написать, как в последних комментах. А то первые я вот тоже не понял.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подытожим то, что @user7860670 сказал (не корысти ради, а токмо ясности для ;)

1) Предложение в вики математически некорректно.
Должно быть - **внутри** описанной около него окружности не находится точек из исходного множества.

2) Проведём диагональ и построим окружность.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно видеть, что четвертая вершина прямоугольника тоже лежит на этой окружности, т.е. это случай, относящийся ко второму свойству из вики

> Как следствие: если никакие четыре точки не лежат на одной окружности,
>   триангуляция Делоне единственна.

Эта фраза тоже не фонтан, из английской более ясен смысл:

> Four or more points on a perfect circle, where the triangulation is
>   ambiguous and all circumcenters are trivially identical.

Действительно, можно провести другую диагональ, это тоже будет валидная триангуляция.

Триангуляция будет не единственной также в случае наличия четырехугольников с суммой противоположных углов, равной 180 градусов (вокруг которых можно описать окружность)

Comment: Хм, а вообще возможны фигуры, которые нельзя разбить на треугольники подходящие под критерии триангуляции Делоне?

Comment: Триангуляция не для фигур, а для набора точек. Про триангуляцию кажется не так наглядно, а вот про двойственное ей [разбиение Вороного](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VoronoiDiagram.html) кажется очевидным, что его можно построить всегда - ничего не мешает провести серединные перпендикуляры между парами точек и ограничить их пересечениями.